Can "length of stay" refers to "the length of time somebody visits somewhere"?
I know that length of stay is "the duration of a single episode of hospitalization", but does it also mean the length of time somebody visits somewhere? If it does, do I have to add something to clarify that I'm talking about tourism, or should I just let readers understand it themselves through context?

Yes, you are correct. Length of stay is commonly used in the hotel/resort industry to describe how long a guest's reservation is. It is also common in fields like customs/boarder control to talk about how long a tourist is planning to be in a country. In most cases, no additional words are needed, because the context is usually clear.
Informal Settings
It is less common in less commercial settings - for example, it would feel slightly out of place when talking about how long my cousin was going to stay with me. It feels like business, political, or medical jargon.
If a friend or relative was scheduled to come stay with me, I would instead say "[name] will be here for 5 days." or "[name] will be staying for 5 days."

+1  But "boarder control" is left to Mrs McGillicuddy to deal with herself :-)
